# Make a webpage inaccessible to all but my PHP script

Tags: php, wampserver, http-status-code-403

How would I be able to make a webpage return HTTP 403 to anyone who tries to access it, apart from my PHP page which fetches data from it? If it helps at all, I'm running [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) server on localhost.

Comment: What stops people from browsing to the PHP page itself to return data?

Comment: All you need to do is figure out an authorization method you would want to use.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html ?

Comment: How do you propose that the server identify "my PHP page which fetches data from it"?

Comment: Assume it is called `mypage.php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.htaccess` method mentioned by Yada is valid. Another approach would be to do this in your PHP script itself. If it's a cronjob running through CLI:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    // If a "remote" address is set, we know that this is not a CLI call
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    die('Access denied. Go away, shoo!');
}
```

Or if it's triggered by a browser request from the other PHP script, just verify if the IP is yours/local:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '192.168.1.5') { // Or whatever your local IP is
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    die('Get out and stay out!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only allow index.php access

.htaccess file

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: .htaccess is a text file in the same folder as your script.  http://www.shariff.org/how-to-enable-htaccess-in-wamp-server.html